# invisible image in python tk canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I have opened an image in python using `PhotoImage()`and put it on the canvas. However, nothing appears on the canvas.

why is it not showing in the canvas or do i need to do anything else?

window and canvas setup:

```
from tkinter import *

w = 960; h = 540

window = Tk()
window.title("Joe's Game")
window.geometry(str(w)+"x"+str(h))

canvas = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas.configure(background='#2B2F37')
canvas.pack()
window.update()
```

image setup:

```
block_mid = PhotoImage("images/block_mid.jpg")
block_cr = PhotoImage("images/block_corner_right.jpg")
block_cl = PhotoImage("images/block_corner_left.jpg")

block_1 = canvas.create_image(60,60,image = block_mid)

canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
window.update()
```

I have checked the file paths and names, but i cant find the cause. It is not producing an error for me to look into. Also, I tried `canvas.pack()`, `canvas.update()` and `window.update()`after the code, but they don't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: `PhotoImage("images/block_mid.jpg")` image on directory but your default path is `/bin/`, try print some content of image(as text). Use `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())` for auto resolve **baseDıR**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to open images this way:

```
block_mid = PhotoImage(Image.open("images/block_mid.jpg"))
# all other images opened this way as well
```

Comment: this returns the error: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type JpegImageFile)

Comment: @JoeAllen, which line exactly is it complaining about? Have you checked the paths are correct? I also don't see `window.mainloop()` in your code.

Comment: i have `window.mainloop()` at the end of the code, but it gives the same error whether it is there or not. the full error is:                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\stuff\Python\game\game.py", line 52, in <module>
    block_1 = canvas.create_image(60,60, image = block_mid)
  File "D:\apps\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2483, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "D:\apps\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2474, in _create
   *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type JpegImageFile)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely getting caught in the garbage collection.

You can prevent this by binding the image to something permanent which python has a reference to, e.g. `window` or `self`, if you are in a class.

i.e., add `window.` in front of your variables to do with the images.